# refresh the uitableview contents

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have added uitableview in which I am trying to add custom UIButton. It is added successfully with this code:

```
    image=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    image.frame=CGRectMake(240, 7, 25, 25);
    image.tag=101;


    image2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    image2.frame=CGRectMake(240, 7, 25, 25);
    image2.tag=102;

    if ([outputlabel.text isEqualToString:@"Yes"]||[outputlabel.text isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell1.contentView addSubview:image];
        [cell1.contentView bringSubviewToFront:image];
    }
    else
    {
        [image2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell1.contentView addSubview:image2];
        [cell1.contentView bringSubviewToFront:image2];
    }
```

Its working fine at first. When table view reload it overlaps the uibutton old image. I am unable to refresh the whole table with new values. Someone has an idea what I am doing wrong in code.

[image]

Comment: Try using [cell1.contentView setNeedsDisplay:True] every time you set image to refresh the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated. Always Create content view for cell in **cell == nil** block. Use that contentview outside by the tag.. Then only it wont overlap and reuse ur cell perfectly..

```
if (cell == nil)
{

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];

//Add your button here.. set the tag.
   UIButton image=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    image.frame=CGRectMake(240, 7, 25, 25);
    image.tag=101;
}


    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];

    if ([outputlabel.text isEqualToString:@"Yes"]||[outputlabel.text isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) 
        {
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
```

Just do like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath.. It will helpful for you..

Comment: @MinkleGarg: Let me jnow wt error you got now? Then you put full coding of cellForRowAtIndexPath and where you [yourTableView reload] put that method also..Then please tell why you use two button use one button vhange the image of that button wait I ll update my code like that

Comment: -(void)finalstatus
{
    statuslisttable.delegate=self;
    statuslisttable.dataSource=self;
    [[self statuslisttable]reloadData];
    [self.view addSubview:transparentpage];
    [self.view addSubview:showstatus];
}

Comment: @MinkleGarg:-(void)finalstatus in this why you set datasource and delegate for your table again.. you set that in -(void)viewDidLoad right thats enough.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if we want to refersh the contents of tableview then need to use this reloadData. Did you try :-

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Yup I did this.. text get updated perfectly but getting issues in images

Comment: What is the issue in images you are getting??

Comment: It gets overlap. Suppose first tym at index 0, there was tick.png image according to array. And table view showing perfectly. But if second time if index 0 contains cross.png image then old image remains the same place and second image also added there.

Comment: Check in your method wher you had written image code . The issue seems not to be refresh because other text is refreshing correctly. Please recheck your code

Comment: You can do one more thing just hide your image on the basis of condition??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implement -cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Then refresh your tableViewCells by calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: on the tableView in question.
The tableView will in turn call cellForRowAtIndexPath, and you simply return the configured cells there.

If you have static cells, you can simply access whatever you need to change by hooking the controls up to an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your cell's view using

```
[cell1.contentView setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];
```

every time you set the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting, that you adding this images in `-tableView:cellForRawAtIndexPath:` method.

First of all - if you reusing cell with some reuse identifier, the Cell will stay in memory and will reused when it needed. It's means that all subviews of your cell will be retained. In this case you need to prepare cell for reusing every time. For example - remove all subViews of cell.

But better way, I recommend in case of less number of operations - to create subclass of UITableViewCell and add UIButton as a property of that cell.

Then you will only need to change this property depend of your condition.

```
if ([outputlabel.text isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
    [cell1.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [cell1.image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Of course, you button must be added in cell.contentView in the Cell initialiser. Usually it is method `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` of your custom cell .m file.